# If $A$ and $a$ are the radii of a triangle's circum- and in-circles, and $b$ the distance between the circles' centers, prove $A^2-b^2=2 A a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

> Given a triangle, denote by $A$ the radius of the circumscribed circle and denote by $a$ the radius of the inscribed circle. The distance between the centers of those circles is $b$. Prove that $A^2 - b^2 = 2Aa$.

I found this in a prelim paper.
I really dont know where to start.
(Sadly, I can only use tangent properties, arc properties and trignometry)

Comment: When the triangle is equilateral, have you proved that $A=2a$? It's just a guess, by I think it will give you some hints of how to proceed when $b\neq 0$.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/aRr.shtml

Answer (score 2):

This is just: [Euler formula in triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry)

Comment: Correct - but link only answers are frowned upon here. They may vanish. Paste in Euler's formula and then give the link.

Comment: Thanks , but the problem is that i can only use tangent properties, arc properties and trignometry . I sadly cant use Eulers formula in a triangle. I havent learnt and i doubt my teacher will accept it .