# A geometry problem from high school Olympiad selection round

Tags: geometry

Consider an isosceles triangle. Let ***r*** be the radius of the circumscribed circle and ***p*** be the radius of the inscribed circle. Prove that the distance d between the centers of these two circles is $$d = \sqrt{r(2p-r)}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $A$ and $a$ are the radii of a triangle's circum- and in-circles, and $b$ the distance between the circles' centers, prove $A^2-b^2=2 A a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452756/if-a-and-a-are-the-radii-of-a-triangles-circum-and-in-circles-and-b-the)

Comment: @greedoid:  I closed that one to this one as we have an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Euler's formula](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/EulerIO.shtml) for a triangle.

Here is the image to give you an idea of how to get the relation.

[image]

By using the paythagoras therorem on different triangles you get 
$$\begin{align}
y &= R - r - h,\\
x &= \sqrt{\rho^{2}-(h+r)^{2}},\\
\rho^{2} &= h^{2}+(a/2)^{2},\\
d^{2} &= x^{2}+y^{2}\\
&= \rho^{2}-(h+r)^{2}+(R-r-h)^{2}\\
&= h^{2}+(a/2)^{2}-(h+r)^{2}+(R-r-h)^{2}\\
&= (a/2)^{2}-2Rr+(R-h)^{2},\\
R^{2}&=(R-h)^{2}+(a/2)^{2}
\end{align}
$$
By solving this we get

$$d^{2}=R^{2}-2Rr$$